# Find and replace in multiple csv files using python

Tags: python, json, data-science, data-cleaning

I have around 40 csv files and I have a file in which I have stored 'find' and 'replace' data.
Like the find column contains values which I need to find and there is a replace column where the replacing text is stored.
Is there a way to automate the process?
[image]
I need to replace all the values in the 40 files that I have with the values given in the picture below.

Comment: To answer you question, yes you can write a script in python to automate the process.
But no one here is going to write that complete program for you.
If you try it yourself and encounter a specific problem on the way, people will be happy to help you.

Comment: Actually,I am able to do it for single file but I don't know how to run a loop for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the files are stored in a particular folder you can use

Import os

Os.listdir(folder_path) 
returns list of all the files
And you can loop your cleaning and replacing script.